# Yarn using wrong $PATH command

Tags: windows, powershell, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I'm relatively new to Windows dev, usually only work on linux/mac. I'm running through some tutorials and tries running:

```
yarn create react-app app
```

but this fails with:

```
yarn create v1.15.2
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Installed "create-react-app@3.0.0" with binaries:
      - create-react-app
[############################################################################################] 92/92'C:\Users\FirstName' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: C:\Users\FirstName LastName\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin\create-react-app
Arguments: app
Directory: C:\Users\FirstName LastName\developer\tutorial
Output:
```

Looking at the output I'm honing in on

```
 Command: C:\Users\FirstName LastName\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin\create-react-app
```

being the issue. So I went to my system settings and see 2 options for yarn,

1. User Path: C:\Users\FirstName LastName\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin
2. System Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\

So I tried deleting the User path to force it onto the System path to no avail. Am I on the right path/$Path (sorry for the pun) here?

Comment: Could be just me, but I fail to see why you have tagged this question `PowerShell`

Comment: User environment takes precedence ovre system environment. Also, the reasonwhy the command fails is that the path to `create-react-app` contains spaces. Which the system path does as well, so the problem would remain the same. I'm not familiar with your toolchain, but you need to either put the path to `create-react-app` in quotes or escape the whitespace in it.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I went into the Advanced settings to try to add either the '\', quotes or '%20' to the UserVariable:$PATH. Quotes is rejected but I tried '\' & '%20' and with each one, even though '$Env:Path' will show that powershell picked up the new Path, it is still failing the same way :/  Also most of the directories in both Paths have spaces, are you sure Windows doesn't just handle that, I feel like my entire Path should be broken if 'C:\Program Files (x86)' isn't a valid Path variable

Comment: I would be surprised if `%20` worked, since that is URL encoding. As for quotes: did you use single or double quotes? Single quotes might not work.